# Is the inner angle of a circle is 180?

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Is this true that polygon with infinitely many sides (which is a circle) 
all inner angles have 180 degrees (each) ?

 by this argument:

$$\frac{(m-2)\cdot180}{m}\space\space\space\Rightarrow\space\space\space180\space-\space\frac{360}{m}\space\space\space\space{\overrightarrow{_{m\rightarrow\infty}}}\space\space\space\space180$$

Is this true?

Comment: What do you mean by "all inner angles"?

Comment: a polygon have inner angles say square 90 pentagon 108

Comment: It makes sense that the inner angle is approaching a straight line.

Answer (score -1):

Technically not exactly 180, as a circle is a curve which doesn't technically have an angle, the best we can do is measure tangent lines. However the limit you have derived I agree with, and it makes sense. $180^0$ is a straight line, and for a circle these lines are hardly noticed because individually they all seem straight, just ever so slightly off the $180^0$ - this causes it to curve around in the fashion we see it do.

Answer (score -1):

I think Yes.
A very small piece of arc on circle seems like a line segment. It get straighter as we decrease the length of arc.
Since circle contains infinite no. of vertices, these small line segments are also a collection of vertices of circle.
Better to say it tends to π

Answer (score -2):

There's no polygon with infinitely many sides. A circle is not a polygon. It has no rectilinear parts, and hence no angles.

Comment: Questions like these shouldn't be attacked bluntly like that. We know a circle isn't a polygon, however it is very much like a polygon with an infinite number of sides, and so, while the OPs comment isn't entirely correct, we can follow the reasoning behind the argument and agree with it

Comment: @RhysHughes There's no such thing as a polygon with infinitely many sides. Polygons always have a positive integral number of sides.

Comment: PS. Concerning your comment, I answered the OP with the truth, instead of egging them on in error like some other answers here. I did not attack anything. I merely clarified things for the OP.